# getting multiple documents with one single requests in bigCouch

Tags: get, bulk, bigcouch

I'm trying to get multiple documents with one single request (http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API#Fetch_Multiple_Documents_With_a_Single_Request) in bigCouch but it doesn't seem to work as expected, it returns all the documents in the DB. 
The same request and with the same data works in couchDB. Isn't it supported in bigCouch?

The request is: http://x.x.x.x:5984/database/_all_docs?keys=["test"]

Comment: It seems that keys parameter is not supported in bigCouch 0.4.0, but it is in master. kudos to the irc cloudant and bigcouchdb crew